# Bootstrap navbar not retracting

Tags: html, navbar, nav, react-bootstrap-nav

Hi guys so I have a problem with my bootstrap navbar. It just doesn't retract. It works on my homepage, everything is funcional but not on my "secondary pages". It is exactly how it is in the index.php with the expection of the `<li>`.

Here's the code:

```
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar smart-scroll navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-dark">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header mx-auto">
  <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="../assets/img/Logo.png"></a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="color: #55dc8d">
    ☰
</button>       
    </div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php" id="sobrenos">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you include a JSFiddle?

Comment: @koder613 External links are discouraged as they can change. A fiddle is ok, but the relevant code must *also* be included in the question itself. A Stack Snippet (creating using the `[<>]`  button on the editor toolbar) is the preferred way to do this on Stack Overflow as it can run directly in the question.

Comment: @Somewowa, are you getting any errors or messages in the console?

Comment: @FluffyKitten I'm not getting any error messages on the console. It just doesn't retract...

Comment: Please see how to create a [MRE] that shows us the problem. The code you posted is not enough to reproduce the problem, and we can't help if we can't see the code that is causing it!